# display get reset to low resolution after kernelBuild

Tags: display, display-resolution

I'm working on a project which is bound to specific linux kernel version
and after I finished kernel-build and reboot into the new kernel, the resolution is reset to the maybe default(1024x768) and there's no other options I can choose in the setting panels.

[old kernel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tevAx.png) vs [new kernel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9Rli.png)

so I'm wondering if there's any way to add specific resolution(1920x1080) in the new kernel or there's some options I need to change/enable so I can bring my old kernel's display setting to the new kernel in the `menuconfig` before KernelBuild.

Thanks for the help .

Comment: Kernels don't deal with screen resolutions, graphics drivers do. Now you know where you should look ;).

Comment: Sorry still a little confused is that mean I need to download the driver or enable the driver support in the menuconfig? thanks